# If $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^p$, Does $f_n^p \rightarrow f^p$ in $L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

If $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^p$, Does $f_n^p \rightarrow f^p$ in $L^1$?

This seems a very trivial fact, but just from looking at the norm definition of convergence, it does not seem entirely clear how $||f_n - f||_p \rightarrow 0$ would imply $||f_n^p - f^p||_1 \rightarrow 0$.

Does the statement hold?

Comment: Write out the definitions and you see it right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that $ 1<p<\infty$. Let $q$ be the conjugate index. $|x^{p}-y^{p} |\leq p(|x|^{p-1}+|y|^{p-1}) |x-y|$ by MVT. To show that $\int |f|^{p-1} |f-f_n| \to 0$ apply Holder's inequality: $\int |f|^{p-1} |f-f_n|  \leq \|f-f_n\|_p (\int |f|^{(p-1)q})^{1/q}$. Since $q(p-1)=p$ we see that $\int |f|^{p-1} |f-f_n| \to 0$. Similarly, $\int |f_n|^{p-1} |f-f_n| \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a name or do you have a link related to that inequality you used?

Comment: A related question: do you know whether $x^p$ is $p$-Hölder continuous when $p\geq 1$ ?

Comment: @DavidHughes Let $x, y >0$. By MVT $x^{p}-y^{p}=p\xi^{p-1} (x-y)$ for  some $\xi$ between $x$ and $y$. If $x<y$ then $\xi^{p-1} <y^{p-1}$ and if $x>y$ then $\xi^{p-1} <x^{p-1}$. In any case  $\xi^{p}\leq x^{p-1}+y^{p-1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and explanation.